# Owin HttpException on Asp.net Web Api and Http Code 504 on the client intermittently

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, katana

We have an Asp.Net Web Api that is using Owin for Authentication and Validation a JWT token.

The issue is when we make some sequential requests with an invalid token (expired one or malformed) we get 504 error in the client and the below error on the server:

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpException 
    Exception message: Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent.
   at System.Web.HttpHeaderCollection.SetHeader(String name, String value, Boolean replace)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallHeaders.AspNetResponseHeaders.Set(String key, String[] values)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.OwinHelpers.AppendHeaderUnmodified(IDictionary`2 headers, String key, String[] values)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider.<.ctor>b__2(OAuthChallengeContext context)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider.ApplyChallenge(OAuthChallengeContext context)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthBearerAuthenticationHandler.ApplyResponseChallengeAsync()
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.<ApplyResponseCoreAsync>d__b.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.<ApplyResponseAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.<TeardownAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.<DoFinalWork>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Here is what I see in Fiddler when I run the same request with an invalid token multiple times:

[image]

As you can see I get the 504 errors that on the Raw tab of fiddler it says:

```
[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a complete response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes.
```

We are using Microsoft.Owin 3.0.1.

Any ideas what's going on here or is there a workaround to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Thats actually a bug in Owin.

According to [this bugreport](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/74) the issue is not fixed yet.